# How to reduce mouse sensivitity?

Tags: windows-xp

Often times when I single click with my new mouse, its treated as a double click for some reason. Is there any setting I can tweak to disable this? I think there's a setting which I set to high for my previous mouse to work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the Mouse section of the Control Panel is a setting for double-click speed.

Your mouse could be going bad, too. Dirt/debris/general wear of the button can cause weird behavior like that.

Comment: thanks, it was already at the slowest possible speed, however i switched the buttons from left to right (so now left button = right click and right = left click), and that fixed it. seems like my mouse's left button had some issue

Answer (score 3):

- Open the **Control Panel**
- If you are not using the Classic-style control panel, click **Printers and Other Hardware**
- Open the **Mouse** control panel
- Under **Double-Click Speed**, set how fast you must click for it to register as a double-click. You can test this setting in the dialog by clicking on the folder icon.

  [image: windows xp mouse settings]